# Debug Celery tasks without CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER

Tags: django, debugging, multiprocessing, celery, scheduled-tasks

I'm facing an issue with Debugging Celery tasks running in a chain.
If I set the CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER configuration the tasks will run on the same process one by one and I'm able to Debug.
but, when I set this configuration another problem is raised, I have an issue creating a socket.

```
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
```

I get an error:

```
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
    error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I can guess it's a result of the CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER configuration.
How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` and instead running the celery worker in a separate tab on your dev machine, like so:

`celery -A proj worker -l INFO`

This way you avoid nasty timing bugs because you dev and live setup behaves the same.

See https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process

Comment: I still cannot debug with that option. no breakpoint is hitting. any idea why?

Comment: You are probably setting breakpoints in the manage.py process and not in the celery process which are running the code inside the task functions. You can specify a logfile to log to with the `-f` option to celery and then do something like `tail -f /tmp/celery.log` to see whats going on. See `celery worker --help` for all the options.